# Storing a string in a variable in php and searching for that variable in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

If I search for a string directly it works properly but whenever I store that string in a variable and try to search that it gives me:

> bool(false)

here is my code

```
<?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
 $roll_no='9999-SO-12';
 echo $roll_no;
 $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT name,title FROM student_data WHERE roll_no=$roll_no");

 var_dump($res);
  ?>
```

But whenever I do it directly It works fine 
for example like this

```
<?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
 $roll_no='9999-SO-12';
 $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT name,title FROM student_data WHERE roll_no='9999-SO-12'");

 var_dump($res);
  ?>
```

So what am I doing wrong? What's the solution?

Comment: @saty I tried your code but it was partially solving my problem. so using  ' ".$roll_no." '  instead of  '$roll_no'  proved helpful.
Further when I tried to store the variable using $_POST your solution wasn't getting the required info but the other one was.So that's why I went for that.
BTW thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameter as integer though it is string. Change your query to:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT name,title FROM student_data WHERE roll_no='".$roll_no."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do some changes like this:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT name,title FROM student_data WHERE roll_no='".$roll_no."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
 $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT name,title FROM student_data WHERE roll_no='".$roll_no."'");
```